# SQL for Multiple rows into one row with different column counts grouped by Category and date

Tags: sql

I have a small sample of one of our tables:

```
User   Category  InitialDate   LastRequestDate   LastUpdate
1      1907      1/1/2010      2/1/2011          1/15/2011
2      6509      6/10/2010     4/1/2011          3/15/2011
3      3102      3/1/2010      3/15/2011         2/17/2011
4      3102      3/1/2010      2/15/2011         3/17/2011
5      6509      5/10/2010     2/1/2011          1/25/2011
6      1907      1/1/2010      3/1/2011          4/15/2011
```

Each user has one row in the table and users are constantly being added.
There are currently about 30 categories but new categories are always being added.

I need to do a summary table for each day for each category what are the counts...

Do you have a suggestion for the best way to handle this besides doing temporary tables, cursors, etc...?  I'm thinking something with row_number partition or / and cte...but not sure how to do this...   Group By won't work because of the dates being on same row...  When use Group by I get a 3 rows for each SKU with duplicate counts...

```
Date           Catalog    InitialCount    LastRequestCount     LastUpdateCount
1/1/2010       1907       2               0                    0       
3/1/2010       3102       2               0                    0
5/10/2010      6509       1               0                    0
6/10/2010      6509       1               0                    0
1/15/2011      1907       0               0                    2
1/25/2011      6509       0               0                    1
2/1/2011       1907       0               1                    0
2/1/2011       6509       0               1                    0
2/15/201       3102       0               1                    0
2/17/2011      3102       0               0                    1
3/1/2011       1907       0               1                    0
3/15/2011      3102       0               1                    0
3/17/2011      3102       0               0                    1
4/1/2011       6509       0               1                    0
4/15/2011      1907       0               0                    1
```

Comment: Which "SQL" database are you using... MySQL, SQL-Server, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Run a pre-query of distinct instances of each category and respective dates... Then, use that as basis to get next level...

```
    select 
          PreQuery.UniqDate,
          PreQuery.Category,
          sum( case when PreQuery.UniqDate = YT.InitialDate then 1 else 0 end ) InitialCount,
          sum( case when PreQuery.UniqDate = YT.LastRequestDate then 1 else 0 end ) LastRequestCount,
          sum( case when PreQuery.UniqDate = YT.LastUpdate then 1 else 0 end ) LastUpdateCount
       from
          ( select distinct
                  Category,
                  InitialDate UniqDate
               from 
                  YourTable
            union
            select
                  Category,
                  LastRequestDate UniqDate
               from
                  YourTable
            union
            select
                  Category,
                  LastUpdate UniqDate ) PreQuery
          join YourTable YT
             on PreQuery.Category = YT.Category
             AND ( PreQuery.UniqDate = YT.InitialDate
                 OR PreQuery.UniqDate = YT.LastRequestDate
                 OR PreQuery.UniqDate = YT.LastUpdate )
      group by
         PreQuery.UniqDate,
         PreQuery.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just take the query you have shown the results for, call it T, and do

```
SELECT Date, Catalog, SUM(InitialCount) AS InitialCount,
             SUM(LastRequestCount) AS LastRequestCount,
             SUM(LastUpdateCount) AS LastUpdateCount
FROM ( /* your existing query goes here */ ) AS T GROUP BY Date, Catalog;
```

Since the two of the three entries are zeroes, does this give what you want?